# Linq query optimization and method syntax equivalent

Tags: linq, entity-framework, postgresql-9.2, npgsql

I have these two queries :

1. The first one gets a distinct list of identifiers.
2. The second filter its result on these ids.

   ```
       var query = (from bk in context.BookKeeping
                    join bk12 in context.BookKeeping on bk.LetteringId equals bk12.LetteringId 
                    into bk11
                    from bk1 in bk11.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join bi2 in context.BillingInformation on bk1.BillingInformationId equals bi2.BillId 
                    into bi1
                    from bi in bi1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where bk.LetteringId != null && bk.PaymentId != null && bk1.LetteringId != null
                    select bk.PaymentId).Distinct();

       var query2 = from m in context.Movement
                    join p2 in context.Payment on m.PaymentId equals p2.Id
                    into p1
                    from p in p1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join pm2 in context.PaymentMode on p.PaymentModeId equals pm2.Id
                    into pm1
                    from pm in pm1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    from ids in query
                    where ids.Value == p.Id
                    select m;
   ```

The interesting part of the second query is following :

```
                 from ids in query
                 where ids.Value == p.Id
```

I would like to know if I could make it more compact and how to filter on a list of ids conditionnaly using the method syntax. I understand that I have to use **SelectMany** but don't know how to choose the right overload.

TIA.

Comment: Didn't you consider to build all this login in SQL rather than force LINQ to translate all this staff to SQL.

Inline table valued function could be considered as a good practice.

Comment: I forgot to add a crucial tag : The database is PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
var query2 = context.Movement.SelectMany(m => query1, (m, ids) => new { m, ids })
    .Where(a => a.m.PaymentId == a.ids).Select(a => a.m);
```

I must say that the syntax of the first lamba was strange at first !